# Repeating mapped text in insert mode

Tags: key-bindings

I am making my life easier by mapping shortcuts to long DocBook XML structures in insert mode, for example

```
map! <unique> <localleader>ct <callout arearefs="">>
```

is there a way to prepend *count* to the mapping in insert mode?
Assuming `,` is my `<localleader>`, if I want to insert the whole `<table>` structure with `,tb`, i could easily insert let's say 20 rows (`,tr`) by typing something like:

```
20,tr
```

Comment: I am not sure about how to do it in insert mode, but I can show you how to do it in normal mode.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to do, but it seems like something that could be easily accomplished with a macro. `qq` to start recording your macro, `q` to stop recording, then `20@q` to replay the macro 20 times. [`:help recording`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#recording)

Comment: From what I understood, he wants to have a command which, when called with a count number, does something `count` times, but not the whole thing (in this case create a single HTML table with `count` rows in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly (cf comments under the question), the following might help you:

```
function! CreateTable(count)
    " Note, the append creates the table from the end to beginning
    call append(line('.'), "</table>")
    call append(line('.'), repeat(["<tr></tr>"], a:count))
    call append(line('.'), "<table>")
endfunc
command -range -nargs=0 CreateTable call CreateTable()
```

And with a mapping (in normal mode) for it:

```
nnoremap <localleader>tr :<C-U>call CreateTable(v:count1)<CR>
```

`<C-U>` cancels the count, to call the function once only (I think this is the good help page: `:h c_CTRL-U`).

`v:count1` in the last count typed (`:help v:count1`).

Comment: What is the `line('.')` part?

Comment: it returns the line number where your cursor is. Cf `:help line`